# #1025 - Error on rename of './database/#sql-2e0f_1254ba7' to './database/table' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb, mysql-error-1025

So I am trying to add a primary key to one of the tables in my database. Right now it has a primary key like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, round_number)
```

Where user_id is a foreign key.

I am trying to change it to this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, round_number, created_at)
```

I am doing this in phpmyadmin by clicking on the primary key icon in the table structure view.

This is the error I get:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './database/#sql-2e0f_1254ba7' to './database/table' (errno: 150)
```

It is a MySQL database with InnoDB table engine.

Comment: A quick search using Google gives me the idea that this problem is related to constraints. Possible helpful links: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html and http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2008/03/mysql_errno_150.html

Answer (score 140, accepted):

There is probably another table with a foreign key referencing the primary key you are trying to change.

To find out which table caused the error you can run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and then look at the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

Comment: In my case, the database was newly created, with no tables at all.

Answer (score 33):

As was said you need to remove the FKs before. On Mysql do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;

ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP INDEX `id_name_fk`;
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me. DROP FOREIGN KEY solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: This solved my problem too, but the same script was working on my development MySQL. Is this a thing that changed in a version of MySQL ?

Answer (score 24):

For those who are getting to this question via google... this error can also happen if you try to rename a field that is acting as a foreign key.

Answer (score 13):

To bypass this in PHPMyAdmin or with MySQL, first remove the foreign key constraint before renaming the attribute.

(For PHPMyAdmin users: To remove FK constrains in PHPMyAdmin, select the attribute then click "relation view" next to "print view" in the toolbar below the table structure)

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to delete a column which is a FOREIGN KEY, you must find the correct name which is not the column name. Eg: If I am trying to delete the server field in the Alarms table which is a foreign key to the servers table.

1. `SHOW CREATE TABLE alarm;`
   Look for the `` CONSTRAINT `server_id_refs_id_34554433` FORIEGN KEY (`server_id`) REFERENCES `server` (`id`) `` line.
2. `` ALTER TABLE `alarm` DROP FOREIGN KEY `server_id_refs_id_34554433`; ``
3. `` ALTER TABLE `alarm` DROP `server_id` ``

This will delete the foreign key server from the Alarms table.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, it is for foreign-key

Click on the **`Relation View`** (like the image below) then find name of the field you are going to remove it, and under the **`Foreign key constraint (INNODB)`** column, just put the select to nothing! Means no foreign-key

[image]

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a foreign key and faced this error, it could be the value in the child table is not present in the parent table.

Let's say for the column to which the foreign key has to be added has all values set to 0 and the value is not available in the table you are referencing it.

You can set some value which is present in the parent table and then adding foreign key worked for me.