# #1025 - Error on rename (errno: 150) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to drop a foreign key(id) in one table(misc) which is the primary key(id) in table(main). db name(xxx)

```
alter table misc drop FOREIGN KEY id
```

I am getting this error

> #1025 - Error on rename of '.\interview#sql-edc_27' to '.\interview\misc' (errno: 150)

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1025 - Error on rename of './database/#sql-2e0f\_1254ba7' to './database/table' (errno: 150)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080611/1025-error-on-rename-of-database-sql-2e0f-1254ba7-to-database-table)

Comment: I have some trouble. This topic help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080611/1025-error-on-rename-of-database-sql-2e0f-1254ba7-to-database-table

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE misc ;
```

You can't drop the foreign key using the column name,run the above query to find out the correct name,something like `misc_ibfk_1`

Heh,IT IS this name:

```
alter table misc drop FOREIGN KEY  misc_ibfk_1
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, was necessary to make a 3-step process (my table is named "articulos", and the hard-to-remove index is "FK_Departamento_ID")

1. For knowing the name of table, I executed:

   ```
   SHOW INDEX FROM articulos;
   ```
2. This statement resolved the issue (#1025, errno: 150), but the index remained in the table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE articulos DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Departamento_ID;
   ```
3. The following statement finally wiped out the index

   ```
   DROP INDEX FK_Departamento_ID ON articulos;
   ```