# MySql Error 1025

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1025

I'm trying to drop a foreign key column in a table I have named ProductInvoice. The column I'm trying to drop is named PersonID and is from the table Person. When I run the query

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice
DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

I get this error...

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './jkripal/#sql-91c_19ff0' to './jkripal/ProductInvoice' (errno: 150)
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this? I've looked around this site and can't find any answers that help.

These are the results from SHOW CREATE TABLE ProductInvoice

```
'ProductInvoice', 'CREATE TABLE `ProductInvoice` 
(\n  `ProductInvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
\n  `PersonID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
\n  `InvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
\n  `TravelDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `TicketNote` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `InsuranceTicketCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductInvoiceID`),
\n  KEY `fkPerson` (`PersonID`),
\n  KEY `fk_ProductInvoice_to_Product` (`ProductID`),
\n  KEY `fk_ProductInvoice_to_Invoice` (`InvoiceID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `Person` (`PersonID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `Product` (`ProductID`),
\n  CONSTRAINT `ProductInvoice_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`InvoiceID`) REFERENCES `Invoice` (`InvoiceID`)
\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Look here on how to find and drop the foreign key http://stackoverflow.com/a/19668812/1745672

Comment: Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ProductInvoice`

Comment: @Mihai I edited the main post

Answer (score 1):

First disable foreign keys

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Delete the key on PersonID

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice
  DROP INDEX fkPerson;
```

Now drop the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP FOREIGN KEY ProductInvoice_ibfk_1;
```

Drop the column

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

Enable foreign keys:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop `Foreign key` first:

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP FOREIGN KEY ....;
```

and then:

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInvoice DROP COLUMN PersonID;
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it won't work. I edited the original post to include the error.

Comment: @RyanDorman You need to use **`FOREIGN KEY` name**. Not column  name

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote these tables, is there a way to find this easily?

Comment: I just found the name and edited it as you said, but for some reason it still will not erase the column. I edited the original post with the updated query and error that I recieve.

Comment: @RyanDorman Drop Index after droping foreign key: `DROP INDEX fkPerson ON ProductInvoice;`

Comment: I tried this. The program fails on the first command, the drop foreign key query.