# Issues importing database from a Mysql 5.0 dump to Mysql 5.5

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have a backup dump from an old Mysql installation created through MySQL Administrator dump 1.4 , Server version   5.0.22-community-nt.

From this dump a need to move a particular database (let's call it "olddatabase") to my Mysql 5.5 installation.

I tried to import it creating a database named "olddatabase" on my installation and executing the command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p olddatabase < c:\olddump.sql
```

but the database is not populated with data, even if mysqldump ends correctly ("Dump completed on...").

I also tried to execute mysql_upgrade, but nothing changed.

I installed Mysql 5.0 on a virtual machine, imported the dump correctly, then I exported the "olddatabase" database throught PhpMyAdmin (4.0.10), and tried to import it throught PhpMyAdmin (4.2.11) on my computer.

I get the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
ADD CONSTRAINT `Mytable_AcquisitionTime` FOREIGN KEY (`acquisitionTime`) REFERENCES `timespans` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `Mytable_CopyOf` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `mytable` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `Mytable_SubtypeOf` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `info` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

#1025 - Error on rename of '.\olddatabase\#sql-87c_63' to '.\olddatabase\mytable' (errno: 150)
```

Any idea why I can't import the database from the dump, or why I get this error?

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: Here's the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080611/1025-error-on-rename-of-database-sql-2e0f-1254ba7-to-database-table (check the constraints)

Comment: The issue come from a "recursive call" on constrants. In some places of the sql file there are constrains like:

     ALTER TABLE `table1`
         ADD CONSTRAINT `Table1_Specialize` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

It is not clear to me why MySQL accepts this code and Mysql 5.5 doesn't accecpt it.