# why I get errno150 when I try to set a primary key as unsigned

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I created a couple of tables on phpmyadmin and now I return to them and I try to edit them and set their primary key as `unsigned`.

The type of the primary key is INT, the Length 11, Default is None, no collation, Not Null, AutoIncreament is true and no Attributes.

I try to change the Attributes to be Unsigned and I get the error

> Query Error : £1025 - Error or rename of
>   './mydatabase/£sql-de8a2_daa21b' to './mydatabase/mytable' (errno:
>   150)

Why I am getting this and how can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080611/1025-error-on-rename-of-database-sql-2e0f-1254ba7-to-database-table

Answer (score 1):

I'm Sure that you are unable to edit cause of Foreign Key relation because there is another table with a foreign key referencing the primary key you are trying to change.

- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table_name]` to show the name of constraint.
- Alter Table for drop foreign_key_constraint_name using `ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP FOREIGN KEY [foreign_key_constraint_name];`
- After that you can edit column name and apply again Foreign Key
  relation.